# Java gridlayout size

Tags: java, layout, grid, size

I'm struggling with java grid layout. I managed to get it working, but the tiles aren't the right size. When I have for example 9 tiles, they are way too big and when I've for example 99 tiles they are way to small.
Here is my code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    int numberOfCol=3;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0,numberOfCol));



    for(int i=0;i<99;i++){
        JTextArea area=new JTextArea("ROW "+ ((i/numberOfCol)+1)  +" COL "+ (i%numberOfCol +1));
        area.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        if( (((i/numberOfCol)+1)+(i%numberOfCol +1))%2 !=1){
            area.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            area.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        panel.add(area);
    }

    JScrollPane scrollPanel=new JScrollPane(panel); //needed to scroll
    frame.add(scrollPanel);
    frame.setSize(600, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I've added a screenshot here: http://s14.postimg.org/5cmh2joen/size.png
Does anyone know how I should change my code, to get the optimal size?
I would also like to get a border around each tile and center the text horizontally and vertically.

Comment: try `panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 600, 30*x ) );` where x is num of rows

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work. Rows are drawn now over eachother + I don't know at the beginning how many rows there will be.

Comment: try add before if this: `area.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600 / numberOfCol , 30));`

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that it creates a horizontal scroll bar. It works for small tiles to make them bigger, but the large tiles are still the same size(= too large).

Comment: you could try only setSize

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also  when I resize the screen, the tiles become larger/smaller.

Comment: then `setPrefferedSize()` which solved small tiles and `setMaximumSize()` with same parameter to solve large tiles

Comment: Thank you, But I just found out there is something called a JTable, I think I'm going to use that. But again Thank you.